# Route function argument with default = null always being injected even when not passed in the URL

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In an old Symfony 4.4 application I inheritted, I have two entities, `Influencer` and `InfluencerManagement`.

The `Influencer` has an `influencerManagement` (represented by `influencer_management_id` in its DB table).

Then I have this route in a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/influencer_management/{influencerManagement}/managers/{influencer}", name="influencer_management_managers", requirements={"influencerManagement"="\d+"})
 */
public function managers(InfluencerManagement $influencerManagement, ?Influencer $influencer = null)
{
    dd($influencer);
    // ...
```

When I go to, for example, `/influencer_management/49/managers/` (no `influencer` passed on the URL's last section), the `dd` call still shows me an influencer - the first one on the table that has `influencer_management_id` set to 49.

I have no idea why it is instantiating the variable when I'm explicitly telling it to default to null if no parameter is passed there. I'm especially confused as to how it "knows" to fetch an `Influencer` that is related to the `InfluencerManagement`. That led me to think it could have something to do with a Repository or an Entity Manager somewhere, but as far as I can tell, none of those things are involved.

Any ideas as to where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, couldn't it be because Symfony try his best to find an influencer and somehow initialize it to something ? Do each request dump the same influencer ? or is it random ? 

I was thinking that it could be initialized to 0 due to the regex ? 
What behavior you are trying to prevent or implement ? Maybe you could put more constraint on the route to not match if the influencer param is empty.

Comment: @Skylli, it's not random; like I said, it picks the first Influencer that has `influencer_management_id` set to the management that is passed in the URL. If you keep the management in the URL, the influencer will always be the same, but it will be different for other managements.

As for what I'm trying to do, I want the `$influencer` argument in the route function to be null if no influencer is passed in the URL. Just like the docs say you should do when you want an optional argument, I am providing a default value for it - null - but instead of null, I get a fully instantiated Influencer.

Comment: With your current data, I get that the param converter return an `Influencer` that have the `influencerManagement` for the given route. But is it always the same ? In the Symfony 4.4 [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/routing.html#optional-parameters) they say you can do `{!blog}` to force the default value when not given. Could it do the trick ? Another idea I have is to `dd(...)` your route parameter in the **kernel-controller** or **kernel-controller-arguments** event. See this [kernel event doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/events.html#kernel-controller) to do so

Comment: It is always the same for the same `influencerManagement` argument. For example, if I go to `/influencer_management/49/managers/` I always get `Influencer` 35; if I go to `/influencer_management/52/managers/` I always get `Influencer` 100. `Influencer` 35 is the first `Influencer` for `InfluencerManagement` 49 and `Influencer` 100 is the first `Influencer` for `InfluencerManagement` 52. Forcing the default value with `!` means I will always get a value for the `influencer` parameter and that is exactly what I don't want. I want to be able to receive a `null` value for the influencer parameter.

Comment: After doing some test, like said in my previous comment, you can subscribe to the `kernel.controller_arguments` event and implement some logic to set your second route parameter to `null`. It is not the prettiest code I've done. It actually reverts what the default paramConverter is doing. But it gives you a `null` value in the controller.

Comment: That sounds like an awful lot of work for something that the docs describe as a trivial little thing (which ends up not even working as they describe). Just shows how messed up Symfony is :( Anyway, thanks a lot for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this behavior [Entity Value Resolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html)

Maybe you need to use [MapEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#mapentity-options) attribute in these place ?

Comment: The Entity Value Resolver sounds like what I'm seeing but the docs say «The EntityValueResolver was introduced in Symfony 6.2.» - The app I inherited is, unfortunately, still using Symfony 4.4, so these docs probably don't apply :( Same thing for the MapEntity - it doesn't seem to exist in the docs for 4.4 :(

Comment: Yes, but this functionality moved from the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle 

https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter

Comment: Ah, got it. And indeed, it does seem to describe exactly what I see: «The converter will attempt to do a findOneBy() fetch by using all of the wildcards in your route that are actually properties on your entity (non-properties are ignored).» So this would fetch the `Influencers` that belong to the `influencerManagement` in the URL, since this is a property of the entity. OK, this gives me something to work with. Thanks! :)